# Function does not repeat when specified

Tags: c++

i have made a function "1" and I want to ask user "Do you want to repeat function "1"?", what am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void temperature()
{
    float c,f;
    cout<<"Áveskite temperatørà pagal Celsijø: ";
    cin>>c;
    f=(c*1.8)+32;
    cout<<"Temperatûra pagal Farenheità: ";
    printf("%2.2f", f);
    cout<<endl;
}



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Lithuanian");
    temperature();
    char isjungti;
    cout<<"Paversti dar vienà temperatûrà?(T)";
    cin>>isjungti;
    if(isjungti == 'T' || 't')
     {
     return temperature(); //I get an error here.              
     }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is your expected behavior? What behavior do you get? What have you tried? Are you aware that there is no loop in your code? What is function "1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` will exit the function scope. Use something like

```
while (isjungti == 'T' || isjungti == 't') {
    temperature()
}
```

Or similar.

Answer (score 2):

`isjungti == 'T' || 't'` is definitely wrong. Also, `return temperature();`, since `temperature()` returns `void`.

You probably meant:

```
 if(isjungti == 'T' || isjungti == 't')
 {
    temperature(); //I get an error here.              
 }
```

Comment: It works, but only once. I execute the program, then I see temperature() function, I type "T" for the temperature() again, I see it, it works, and after temperature() ends I see "Press any key to continue..."

Comment: @user1804119 yes. And? What makes you think it should run multiple times? Do you have any loops in the code?

Comment: It should ask for repeating temperature() again, then, if I type "T" or "t" it should execute tempereture() and ask for repeating untill, after a question for repeating I type not "T" or "t". Sorry if I made any mistakes, my main Language isn't English and Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @user1804119 I understood what the requirement is, I don't understand why you think it should behave like that without using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

main() is int, your function doesn't return anything. Strip "return" from the erroneous line just to call the function and read up on return values.